# How to map fields using custom mapper and save fields names mapping in MapperFacade or MapperFactory?

Tags: java, mapping, orika

There are two classes. One of them have field with `FunctionalInterface` type. I need to map field `nameA` from `ClassA` to `base` from `ClassB`. I can make it with custom mapper but then I will not have fields names mapping in MapperFacade (e.g. "nameA" <-> "base" in fieldsMapping Collection), but I need it for further mathing in other method. If I map them with fields names then I get an Exception that java can't map String to CustomFunctionalInterface.
Is there something way to resolve it (map `nameA` into `base` and have fields names mapping in MapperFacade or MapperFactory)?

```java
package project.my;

public class ClassA {
    String nameA;

    public String getNameA() {
        return nameA;
    }

    public void setNameA(String nameA) {
        this.nameA = nameA;
    }
}
```

```java
package project.my;

public class ClassB {
    CustomFunctionalInterface base;

    public CustomFunctionalInterface getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(CustomFunctionalInterface base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
}
```

```java
package project.my;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface CustomFunctionalInterface {
    String name();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched resolution in orika documentation, but haven't found anything related to this question. I think there is no good way to resolve this issue. With customMappers you can't fill fieldsMapping with needed fields relationship. Similary to converters (for this case). My workaround:

```java
...
   .fieldMap("nameA", "base").bToA().exclude().add()
...
```

When you exclude mapping relationship will be written in fieldsMapping (but with "<-" relation instead of "<->"). In my case this exclusion doesn't have sense, but relationship will be existed in fieldMappind (or classMapping)